# Smack Openfire Android Unable to send message to Group/Room Error 403 forbidden

Tags: java, android, openfire, smack

```
MultiUserChatManager manager = MultiUserChatManager.getInstanceFor(xmppconnection.getConnection());
try {
    MultiUserChat muc = manager.getMultiUserChat("test2@conference.cca");

    muc.join("test2@conference.cca");

    Message msg = new Message("test2@conference.cca", Message.Type.groupchat);
    msg.setBody("Hi Testing..Group chat..");
    muc.sendMessage(msg);
    // muc.join("test", "1234");
} catch (SmackException.NotConnectedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (SmackException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (XMPPException.XMPPErrorException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (XMPPException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Error is:

> error code="403" type="auth" forbidden xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/>**

Comment: is it room id.. `getMultiUserChat("test2@conference.cca");`?

Comment: yes its room id. getting information of user but unable to send message after joining the group.

Comment: @DimaSan yes it is

Comment: n what is this .. `muc.join("test2@conference.cca");`.. i think it should be `user_id`.. not `group id`.

Comment: @sourabhbans its group id and i want to send message to group

Comment: but it should be .. `user_id`(who want to join the group).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several errors, logical and procedurals.

With this invocation:

```
 MultiUserChat muc = manager.getMultiUserChat("test2@conference.cca");
```

you have in **muc object** your groupchat.
So you need to check if you already joined this groupchat or double join will raise an exception.

so

```
if (!muc.isJoined())
 muc.join("My nickname");
```

more, when you join, you MUST provide an unique nickname per User to join, or you'll obtain an exception with the second user. Set as nickname the same name of the groupchat it's 99% a logical error.

Finally, to send a message, just send it through MUC object or you'll risk, like in this case, to miss some information.

So just send it with

```
muc.send("Hi Testing..Group chat..");
```

Last but not least: of course multiuserchat must exists or inititilized before properly, it's a prerequisite to do all this. As first step, just create it in Openfire with http-admin-panel (make it persistant)